# Objective C frame animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im reading a tutorial to animate sprite sheet frames in objective-C, 
code below shows how to allocate and initialize a mutable array and loop
through it using a for loop.

```
NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        NSString *frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%04i.png",i];
    }
```

i can't understand how this piece of code works :

```
:@"a%04i.png",i
```

note that i have sprites name like this : a0001.png till ,a0031.png. simply tell me how a%4i
works here ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the translation is not very hard:

```
:@"a%04i.png",i  

@"a" + @"integerWith4digits" + @".png" == @"a0000.png";
```

i.e. if the integer is 1 then complete the integer by adding 3 zeros (0001), if the integer is 1111 or 1111..., then do nothing

Comment: and what is the role of %?

Comment: This is C language format identifier. Everything with C identifier will be changed with the correspond type. On your example '%i' will be changed with integer 'i' from your for loop.
Here is a link http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html